# How to convert HSSFWorkbook object into XSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

I am using Spring 3 `AbstractExcelView` to use export - to - excel functionality to download file  into `.xls` format but when my rows are greater than 65536, it throws an exception:

> Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)

I want to use `XSSFworkbook` to create `.xlsx` file but the method of `AbstractExcelView` which I have overridden,

```
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
            HSSFWorkbook wb, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {}
```

only takes `HSSFWorkbook` as an argument which I want to convert into `XSSFWorkbook` object to create `.xlsx` format file.

Answer (score 2):

The [Apache POI guide to converting existing HSSF Usermodel code to SS Usermodel (for XSSF and HSSF)](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html) covers the very case you're asking about

It's possible, with a fairly small amount of work, to convert you code so that it works transparently for both HSSF (.xls) and XSSF (.xlsx) via the new common interfaces.

For your specific case, it looks like you'll need to get the sourcecode for your spring module, convert that as described in the guide, then contribute back a patch.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have tried, but if you followed the instructions to update you code it'll be just fine! You do need to change all of your code though to support XSSF, if you only change half to use the SS interfaces then it'll continue to work for HSSF but XSSF won't

Answer (score 1):

it seems this is not yet possible, see the improvement request at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6898 which is not yet fixed...